# Addition of values to binary tree in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm very very new to the language prolog

Comment: I believe the `@<` and `@>/2` operators will do what you need, but the little bit of code you show so far isn't valid Prolog. There are very basic syntax errors. Do you have a Prolog textbook to review, or have to gone through any tutorials?

Comment: Well, no but it will be very kind of you if you can help me with this.

Comment: For tutorials, there are a couple online to help you get used to basic syntax and list processing. There's [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online) and [this one](http://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/contents.html). For text, there are some online, such as [Guide To Prolog Programming](http://kti.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/contents.html), or you can get a book such as, *Programming in Prolog: The ISO Standard* by Clocksin and Mellish. Any of these will h help you get started understanding the basic, correct syntax, and more.